# Want overwrite a file with panda using .to_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
I am using Win 10, python version 3.7.10, pandas version 1.3.3
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 7.28.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.0.6
jupyter_core     : 4.8.1
jupyter_server   : 1.11.1
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.5.4
nbconvert        : 6.2.0
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.4
qtconsole        : 5.1.1
traitlets        : 5.1.0
```

When I do it a second time I get error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'datasets\titanic\X_train.csv'

Here is the code:

```
def save_titanic_data(df, titanic_path=TITANIC_PATH):
    dsname = ".".join((df.name, "csv"))
    csv_path = os.path.join(titanic_path, dsname)
    df.to_csv(csv_path)
    return

X_train.name = "X_train"
save_titanic_data(X_train)
```

It fails here:

```
<ipython-input-24-0302d8dc9559> in save_titanic_data(df, titanic_path)
      2     dsname = ".".join((df.name, "csv"))
      3     csv_path = os.path.join(titanic_path, dsname)
----> 4     df.to_csv(csv_path)
      5     return
      6
```

and the final error output is:

```
~\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    705                 encoding=ioargs.encoding,
    706                 errors=errors,
--> 707                 newline="",
    708             )
    709         else:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'datasets\\titanic\\X_train.csv'
```

The documentation says that to.csv always overwrites, so I am surprised that is works once, then fails thereafter.

Comment: It always overwrites, if you have the permission to write. Perhaps there's a default setting on your computer such that when a file is created, you don't have permission to write? Have you tried editing that csv file with a text editor?

Comment: Is the csv closed which you want to overwrite?

Answer (score 0):

Add `csv_path.close()` before your `return` in the `save_titanic_data()` function